# Unable to get user from kerberos for ldap authentication interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, kerberos

> I am using kerberos for authentication and ldap for authorization.
>   My kerberos authentication is working fine. Problem I am facing is ldap is called before kerberos returns username.
>   My ldap code is inside an interceptor, which is called first but it gets request.getRemotUser() as null and kerberos returns username after this as I can see in logs.
>   So how to call kerberos first and then ldap?
>   My ldap code is inside springs HandlerInterceptorAdaptor's preHandlerMethod inside Interceptor class :

```
@override
public boolean preHandler(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Object handler){
 String userName = request.getRemoteUser();
...
  if (isAuthorized(userName)) {
    //setting userName in session here
  }
  else {
    //ldap authentication failed
  }
}
```

> Interceptor is defined in application-servlet.xml and kerberos is configured in security-config.xml , and both entries are made in web.xml. security-config.xml is before application-servlet.xml in web.xml
>   So in above code I get username as null but in logs when kerberos is called it returns me username. Sorry for not posting detailed code. I hope this question is understandable.

Comment: Care to close this question or place a comment why the given answer doesn't count as such? Now, it will show up as open, possibly confusing other users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not quite understand the question / the problem your trying to solve, but why not inject a [LdapUserDetailsServiceImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsImpl.html),  as the UserDetailsService of your [KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/kerberos/authentication/KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.html)?

That way Kerberos is doing the authentication and Ldap the authorization (i.e. populating the [LdapUserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetails.html) object).